# for loop does not stop even after condition is met [Node, asyn await]

Tags: node.js, for-loop, async-await, promise

I am trying to stop for loop on certain condition but loop continuous even if use break on certain condition.

Following is the code,

```
  let statusKey = 0;
  
  const terminateLoop = async function () {
   statusKey = 1;
   mainFn()
  }

  const doSomething = async function () {
    for (let i of temAnotherArr) {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       execFile(`/temp/abc.sh`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(error)
        if (error) {
          reject();
        } else {
          resolve()
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

const mainFn = async function () {
  for (let i of tempArr) {
    if (statusKey === 1) {
      doSomething();
      return;
    } else {
     await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      execFile(`/temp/xyz.sh`,(error, stdout, stderr) => {
          console.log(error)
          if (error) {
            reject();
          } else {
            resolve()
          }
        });
     });
    }
   }
 }

 mainFn();
```

Initially mainFn() gets called and it starts looping tempArr, after certain time from UI user clicks on button which trigger terminateLoop() function and statusKey gets change to 1 then same mainFu() gets called. It enters into if condition and calls function doSomething(). But once doSomething() completes, else condition still gets executes. I am not sure why loop is not breaking. I guess it has something to do with async await and Promise. I am not sure how to break this and not sure what I am making mistake.

Answer (score 0):

> But once `doSomething()` completes, `else` condition still gets executes.

The `else` will not execute from scratch, but do realise that there can be a pending callback call from that `execFile` in the `else` block that is still to happen after `statusKey` has been set to 1. When eventually that callback is called, your code will still execute that `console.log` without having regard of `statusKey`'s value.

Furthermore, your code then resolves the promise that is being awaited in the `else` block and then the execution context of `mainFn` is resumed in that `else` block. So yes, it is possible that some code in the `else` block still executes *after* `statusKey` has been set to 1, but it is not possible that the `else` block is executed from scratch. You can be sure that this `execFile` function is *not* called anymore from that particular spot in the code when `statusKey` is 1. Only its callback could still be called and any statements that follow the `await` in the `mainFn` context (your example code has no such statements).

So the easiest "fix" is to also add an `if` statement inside that callback, and have it test the value of `statusKey`.

Unrelated, but I would avoid code repetition and *promisify* the `execFile` function.